# Is it possible to place objects in hierarchies so that object names can be retained during copy?

Tags: dupli-groups

Is it possible to create Blender objects into a group, so that the object names that are part of the group are contained within the hierarchy?

Perhaps another way to ask the question, is there some way to put object names into a hierarchy and not have all object names at the global scope?

Here is a small example of the question:

[image: simple Parent-Children group]

In the picture, the objects have the following parent-child relationships:

```
    Plane
      |-- Text.plane
      |-- Cube.A
      |     |-- Text.cubeA
      |
      |-- Cube.B
            |-- Text.cubeB
```

- the desired outcome is be able to copy parent "Plane" as a top-level object, but its children are copy unchanged (inside the hierarchy) and we end up with object names like this:

  ```
  Plane                     Plane.001
    |-- Text.plane             |-- Text.plane
    |                          |
    |-- Cube.A                 |-- Cube.A
    |     |-- Text.cubeA       |     |-- Text.cubeA
    |                          |
    |-- Cube.B                 |-- Cube.B
          |-- Text.cubeB       |     |-- Text.cubeB
  ```

Why would you want to do this "hierarchal copy"?

Well imagine that the original "Plane" object and its children were all fitted out with logic bricks that controlled color, animation, etc.  And, all of the control of these changes was activated by message sensors.  The messages are organized so that an outside controller makes changes by sending all change messages to the top-level object "Plane".  If the message is meant for a child, then "Plane" simply passes it on down.

If one is able to do the "hiearchy copy", then every child object and child object name, including logic bricks and their contents, can be copied unchanged, and the new "Plane.001" object can be controlled exactly like the original "Plane" object.

If one simply copies a parent object now, each object within the parent-child group is given a new object name at the global scope (by adding ".001"), like this:

```
    Plane                     Plane.001
      |-- Text.plane             |-- Text.plane.001
      |                          |
      |-- Cube.A                 |-- Cube.A.001
      |     |-- Text.cubeA       |     |-- Text.cubeA.001
      |                          |
      |-- Cube.B                 |-- Cube.B.001
            |-- Text.cubeB             |-- Text.cubeB.001
```

This requires that all logic bricks be updated manually with the new names, since the copied bricks will continue to point to the original object names.

The other type of group duplication I have found called "group instance" is also insufficent, since the copied group does not create new objects that can be independently controlled.

(Given the "Class" nature of Python, seems like "hierarchal copy" ought to be feasible.  Am I really asking how to create a "Plane" Class and then how to instantiate copies of "Plane"?)

Comment: I understand you want for this feature, but nope not possible. It is just how blender handles datablocks.